# How to use autoresize on 2 UIViewControllers?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 `UIViewController`s:

```
UIViewControllers1
UIViewControllers2
```

`UIViewControllers2.view` is added as subView to `UIViewControllers1.view`.

And the problem is that `UIViewControllers2.view` doesn't want to autoresize when `UIViewControllers1.view` is resizing (`UIViewControllers1 setFrame:frame`).

```
[UIViewControllers1.view setAutoresizesSubViews:YES]
[UIViewControllers1.view setAutoResizeMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)]
[UIViewControllers1.view addSubview:UIViewControllers2.view];
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `UIViewControllers2.view setAutoresizeSubViews:YES` You mean `UIViewControllers1.view` - that is the view that is supposed to resize its subviews when it itself is resized.

Comment: Okay, so, this code is bogus. There is no `setAutoresizeSubViews:`, it is `setAutoresizesSubviews`. There is no `setAutoResizeMask:`. Do not show fake code. Paste in your real and true code if you want help. You must show what you are *actually* doing, not make up something fictitious.

Comment: Thanks, the code is fixed. Real code is more complex to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, part of the problem is that this is illegal:

```
[UIViewControllers1.view addSubview:UIViewControllers2.view];
```

You must never just wantonly add one view controller's view to another view controller's view. There is only one way in which that is allowed outside of a built-in parent-child structure that does it for you (UINavigationController, UITabBafController, UIPageViewController), and that is when you create your *own* elaborate custom parent-child structure - and you are not doing that. The architecture needed for doing that is described in my book here:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

To be clear, there is nothing whatever wrong with adding a view to another view! The ability to make views come and go is crucial to iOS. What's wrong is that you must not add a *view controller's view* to another view, except under the parent-child view controller architecture, built-in or custom.

Comment: I just use third-party component and it has `UIViewController`. So, should I remove it from the component? But it's too hard. Is it possible to force autoresizing to work?