# How do I keep an object created within a method alive in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I want to place multiple pie charts in my application that I create using core plot. I made a wrapper class (lets call it `PieChartViewControlle`r) that is a view controller and sets up the graph and some buttons and actions to make the graph interactive. To deploy it, I usually just create a property on another view controller that holds the `PieChartViewController` and when I am initializing this view controller I simply alloc/init the`PieChartViewController` and add its view to the main view. This usually works fine.

The problem is that on another view, I want to add a variable amount of graphs to the view and this number is decided when the view controller is initialized. I have a method that initializes each `PieChartViewController` and adds it to an `NSMutableDictionary` on the parent so that I could keep a reference to them. However, this doesn't seem to keep them alive because I always get **BAD_ACCESS** 2 crashes and when running instruments I realized that they get deallocated.

So when the `PieChartViewControllers` are stored on a property it's all good, but when I put them in a dictionary they seem to not be kept alive long enough. I am still not very familiar with memory management in objective-c and I'm not really sure how to go about this, would appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe you should show some code - the method that inits the PieChartViewControllers and adds them to the dictionary. Is the dictionary getting deallocated? How are you holding on to it?

Comment: Ever since implementation of ARC - memory managament in iOS obj-c is no more a thing to be affraid of. But, as He Was said: you should post some code or give more details (not in a Hemmingway novel kind of way though) to get a good answer. Actually, some code would be best.

Comment: @rokjarc - Actually, before ARC we'd know exactly what to tell the guy to do -- `retain` the object, then `release` it when it was no longer needed.  Since ARC it's often more difficult to decide how to fix odd cases.

Comment: @HotLicks: yeah, that's true. Back then with responsibility a programmer also had a bit more control over this. My comment was actually motivated by some questions when new (to obj-c) coders are following old (& good) tutorials. Since ARC usually a use of `performSelector:afterDelay:0.1` fixes 80% of all glitches :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I simply alloc/init the PieChartViewController and add its view to the main view. This usually works fine

It may work fine, but don't do it. This is a misuse of UIViewController. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962125/341994

Comment: Whether doing that or not was acceptable was actually the other question I had, thanks for clarifying. How would you recommend going about this? The charts need a delegate that manages their data and their appearance. I would like for each graph to be self contained in an object, with their data and their name and some gestures that I use with them all stored together rather than having to deal with data for multiple graphs from the parent view controller. That is why I had chosen to add several view controllers as if they were UI elements. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the link I gave you. You can make your own hierarchy of view controllers and their views, but you have to do it the right way, using the proper parent-child view controller architecture and sending all the right messages as you manipulate the view.